# Eclipse PHP Zend debugger

Tags: php, eclipse, debugging

I have Linux Ubuntu with a lamp stack apache2 php52 mysql51.
I have Eclipse Helios which has php52 and 53 plugins.

A Launch Debug config requires a server name/host name like localhost.

Is the Eclipse php cli pumping the output to localhost?

The localhost in a browser has the mysql connector working.

The Eclipse Debug internal php cli doesnt.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get Xdebug 2.1.0 with php 5.3.2 and mysql to work in Eclipse Helios PDT on Ubuntu Lucid 10.4 x86_64.

Back tracking to php52 might be impossible.  Unless you can get 52 to compile with the new Zend API.